# total_virtual_address_space_kb very high

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU11) - 12.0.5579.0 (X64) the query :

```
select total_virtual_address_space_kb from sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

gives : 8 589 934 464 kb

So it's 8 589 Gb... Far from any reality. Is it some kind of dream that the SQL Server process have about memory ? A known bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a max "limit" of total potentially addressable space. For example, it's the same as if you were telling what the max possible phone number is that you can make with a seven-digit dialing, so: 9 999 999

It's true that it's not tremendously useful information, especially just aside the actual and real physical memory currently in use in the field `physical_memory_in_use_kb` of the same system view `sys.dm_os_process_memory`...

Note that on a Windows Server (x64), SQL Server can "dream" as you say of 137 438 953 344 KB! So even more.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Address Space is the theoretical limit of memory available to a process in the operating system. This is not related to the physical amount of memory in the system; but a combination of operating system preference and 32bit/64bit setting.

On Windows 64 bit, this value is 8tb. That's the value that you're seeing. It's not a bug, it's not a SQL peculiarity, it's your misunderstanding what the column you're looking at tells you.

For more information, take a look at:

- [Virtual Address Space on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)
- [`sys.dm_os_process_memory` docs on BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-process-memory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @fasa I'm sorry if you took offence to my wording, it wasn't my intention. have a nice day.